# "Use Schema.org Markup" setting in All in one SEO > General Settings

Tags: seo

When I check the setting "Use Schema.org Markup" in All in one SEO > General Settings, the below code is generated:

```
itemscope 
itemtype="http://schema.org/WebSite" 
prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" >
```

What is this code about?

Comment: Is "All in one SEO" a plugin for WordPress?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use schema.org to provide rich snippets (http://schema.org/WebSite)

From [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/discovery-and-monetization/social-discovery/?hl=en):

> **Add "itemscope" to define microdata scope**
>
> By adding itemscope, you can
>   specify the tag as a block of contents about a particular item.
>
> **Add "itemtype" to define type of your website**
>
> The type of item can be
>   specified using the itemtype attribute along with the itemscope. The
>   value of an itemtype can be determined according to the type of the
>   content on your webpage.

2. Use Open Graph Protocol (OGP) to provide rich snippets (og:http://ogp.me/ns#)

It is called Open Graph protocol markup. From the [Open Graph protocol](http://ogp.me/) site:

> The Open Graph protocol enables any web page to become a rich object
>   in a social graph. For instance, this is used on Facebook to allow any
>   web page to have the same functionality as any other object on
>   Facebook.

Comment: Please note that you need to quote any text copied from other websites and include an attribution link.

Comment: Do i need to add anything else in this code or it's enough to have the default code that's output after  I check the setting "Use Schema.org Markup" in All in one SEO > General Settings?